# PHP Pthread: The procedure entry point _zend_hash_update could not be located

Tags: php, pthreads

I want to install PHP pThread for PHP 7.4.9 x64 with Wamp, I tried multiple versions non of them worked, with the last version ( php_pthreads-3.1.6-7.0-ts-vc14-x64.zip ) in this link: https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/3.1.6/
after I did all steps in this link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php#115004
and when I start the server it shows me an error:

```
The procedure entry point _zend_hash_update@@24 could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.9\ext\php_pthreads.dll
```

I can't enable pThread with PHP 7.4.9 x64.

Comment: Do you have the PHP-TS version installed?

Comment: Yes Thead Safety Enabled

Comment: The error sounds like you have a wrong dll at the given path.

Comment: That's what I think, but this is the last version on the official website

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with pthreads in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54007662/problems-with-pthreads-in-php)